# Package GWmodel fails to load

Tags: r, r-package, r-raster, gwmodel

Version `2.2-9` of `GWmodel` (installed from `CRAN`) fails to load. Reinstalling the package does not fix the problem either. I also tried `detaching` all loaded packages and tried loading the package again but it fails. I guess the issue is related to how packages `spacetime` (`STFDF-class function`) and `raster` (`RasterBrick function`) are being loaded by `GWmodel`. I tried searching the issue on `Github` and most of the issues are related to the `gstat` package and there doesn't seem to be a clear solution for this problem.

```
detachAllPackages <- function() {

  basic.packages <- c("package:stats","package:graphics","package:grDevices","package:utils","package:datasets","package:methods","package:base")

  package.list <- search()[ifelse(unlist(gregexpr("package:",search()))==1,TRUE,FALSE)]

  package.list <- setdiff(package.list,basic.packages)

  if (length(package.list)>0)  for (package in package.list) detach(package, character.only=TRUE)

}

detachAllPackages()
```

How can I fix this?

Error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘GWmodel’:
 package slot missing from signature for generic ‘coerce’
and classes STFDF, RasterBrick
cannot use with duplicate class names (the package may need to be re-installed)
```

Session info:

```
─ Session info ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
 os       Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)
 system   x86_64, mingw32
 ui       RStudio
 language (EN)
 collate  English_United States.utf8
 ctype    English_United States.utf8
 tz       America/New_York
 date     2022-09-12
 rstudio  2022.07.1+554 Spotted Wakerobin (desktop)
 pandoc   2.18 @ C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)

─ Packages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package           * version  date (UTC) lib source
 abind             * 1.4-5    2016-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 assertthat          0.2.1    2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 backports           1.4.1    2021-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 bitops              1.0-7    2021-04-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 boot                1.3-28   2021-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 broom               1.0.0    2022-07-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 cachem              1.0.6    2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 callr               3.7.1    2022-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 car                 3.1-0    2022-06-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 carData             3.0-5    2022-01-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 cellranger          1.1.0    2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 class               7.3-20   2022-01-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 classInt            0.4-7    2022-06-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 cli                 3.3.0    2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 cluster             2.1.3    2022-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 coda                0.19-4   2020-09-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 codetools           0.2-18   2020-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 colorspace          2.0-3    2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 cowplot           * 1.1.1    2020-12-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 crayon              1.5.1    2022-03-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 crosstalk           1.2.0    2021-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 curl                4.3.2    2021-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 data.table          1.14.2   2021-09-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 DBI                 1.1.3    2022-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 dbplyr              2.2.1    2022-06-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 deldir              1.0-6    2021-10-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 DEoptimR            1.0-11   2022-04-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 devtools          * 2.4.4    2022-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 digest              0.6.29   2021-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 dplyr             * 1.0.9    2022-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 e1071               1.7-11   2022-06-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 ellipsis            0.3.2    2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 evaluate            0.16     2022-08-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 expm                0.999-6  2021-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 fansi               1.0.3    2022-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 farver              2.1.1    2022-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 fastmap             1.1.0    2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 forcats           * 0.5.1    2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 forecast            8.16     2022-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 foreign             0.8-82   2022-01-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 fracdiff            1.5-1    2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 fs                  1.5.2    2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 gargle              1.2.0    2021-07-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 gdata               2.18.0.1 2022-05-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 generics            0.1.3    2022-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 ggmap             * 3.0.0    2019-02-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 ggplot2           * 3.3.6    2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 ggpubr            * 0.4.0    2020-06-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 ggsignif            0.6.3    2021-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 glue                1.6.2    2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 gmodels             2.18.1.1 2022-05-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 googledrive         2.0.0    2021-07-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 googlesheets4       1.0.0    2021-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 gridExtra         * 2.3      2017-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 gtable              0.3.0    2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 gtools              3.9.3    2022-07-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 haven               2.5.0    2022-04-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 hms                 1.1.1    2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 htmltools         * 0.5.3    2022-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 htmlwidgets       * 1.5.4    2021-09-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 httpuv              1.6.5    2022-01-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 httr                1.4.3    2022-05-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 intervals           0.15.2   2020-04-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 jpeg                0.1-9    2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 jsonlite            1.8.0    2022-02-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 KernSmooth          2.23-20  2021-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 knitr               1.40     2022-08-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 labeling            0.4.2    2020-10-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 later               1.3.0    2021-08-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 lattice             0.20-45  2021-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 lazyeval            0.2.2    2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 leaflet           * 2.1.1    2022-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 leaflet.providers   1.9.0    2019-11-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 LearnBayes          2.15.1   2018-03-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 lifecycle           1.0.1    2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 lmtest              0.9-40   2022-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 lubridate           1.8.0    2021-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 lwgeom              0.2-8    2021-10-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 magrittr            2.0.3    2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 maptools          * 1.1-4    2022-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 MASS                7.3-57   2022-04-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 Matrix            * 1.4-1    2022-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 memoise             2.0.1    2021-11-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 mgcv                1.8-40   2022-03-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 mime                0.12     2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 miniUI              0.1.1.1  2018-05-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 modelr              0.1.8    2020-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 munsell             0.5.0    2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 nlme                3.1-157  2022-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 nnet                7.3-17   2022-01-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 patchwork         * 1.1.1    2020-12-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 pillar              1.8.0    2022-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 pkgbuild            1.3.1    2021-12-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 pkgconfig           2.0.3    2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 pkgload             1.3.0    2022-06-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 plotly            * 4.10.0   2021-10-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 plyr                1.8.7    2022-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 png                 0.1-7    2013-12-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 prettyunits         1.1.1    2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 prism             * 0.2.0    2020-12-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 processx            3.7.0    2022-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 profvis             0.3.7    2020-11-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 promises            1.2.0.1  2021-02-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 proxy               0.4-27   2022-06-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 ps                  1.7.1    2022-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 purrr             * 0.3.4    2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 quadprog            1.5-8    2019-11-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 quantmod            0.4.20   2022-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 R6                  2.5.1    2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 randomcoloR       * 1.1.0.1  2019-11-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 raster            * 3.5-29   2022-08-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 RColorBrewer      * 1.1-3    2022-04-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 Rcpp              * 1.0.9    2022-07-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 readr             * 2.1.2    2022-01-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 readxl              1.4.0    2022-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 remotes             2.4.2    2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 reprex              2.0.1    2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 reshape2          * 1.4.4    2020-04-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 rgdal             * 1.5-32   2022-05-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 RgoogleMaps         1.4.5.3  2020-02-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 rjson               0.2.21   2022-01-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 rlang               1.0.5    2022-08-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 rmarkdown           2.14     2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 robustbase        * 0.95-0   2022-04-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 rstatix             0.7.0    2021-02-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 rstudioapi          0.13     2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 Rtsne               0.16     2022-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 rvest               1.0.2    2021-10-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 s2                  1.1.0    2022-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 scales              1.2.0    2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 sessioninfo         1.2.2    2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 sf                * 1.0-8    2022-07-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 sfheaders         * 0.4.0    2020-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 shiny               1.7.1    2021-10-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 simplevis         * 6.3.0    2022-06-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 sp                * 1.5-0    2022-06-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 spatialreg        * 1.2-3    2022-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 spData            * 2.0.1    2021-10-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 spdep               1.2-4    2022-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 splitstackshape   * 1.4.8    2019-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 stars             * 0.5-6    2022-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 stringi             1.7.8    2022-07-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 stringr           * 1.4.1    2022-08-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 terra             * 1.6-7    2022-08-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 tibble            * 3.1.7    2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 tidyr             * 1.2.0    2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 tidyselect          1.1.2    2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 tidyverse         * 1.3.2    2022-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 timeDate            3043.102 2018-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 tseries             0.10-51  2022-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 TTR                 0.24.3   2021-12-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 tzdb                0.3.0    2022-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 units               0.8-0    2022-02-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 urca                1.3-0    2016-09-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 urlchecker          1.0.1    2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 usethis           * 2.1.6    2022-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 utf8                1.2.2    2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 V8                  4.2.0    2022-05-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 vctrs               0.4.1    2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 viridisLite         0.4.0    2021-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 weathermetrics    * 1.2.2    2016-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 withr               2.5.0    2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 wk                  0.6.0    2022-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 xfun                0.32     2022-08-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 xml2                1.3.3    2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 xtable              1.8-4    2019-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 xts                 0.12.1   2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 yaml                2.3.5    2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 zoo                 1.8-10   2022-04-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
```

Update:

As Ben pointed out `spacetime` is not in the `sessioninfo list`, so I tried loading the package `spacetime` version `1.2-8` and it fails to load after detaching all of the loaded packages with the same error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘spacetime’:
 package slot missing from signature for generic ‘coerce’
and classes STFDF, RasterBrick
cannot use with duplicate class names (the package may need to be re-installed)
```

Comment: weird.  I don't see `spacetime` listed in your session info. What is `packageVersion("spacetime")` (I have 1.2.8)? Can you try this in a clean R session (I see packages in the list like `plotly` that shouldn't have been loaded automatically)?

Comment: @BenBolker thank you for pointing that out, so I tried loading the `spacetime` package which returns the same error after detaching all of the loaded packages as shown in the updated question.

Comment: @BenBolker yes `GWmodel` loads `successfully` in a clean R session. So, I guess I should load `GWmodel` first before loading another package right? But, I don't know why the `detach` function didn't work instead of restarting `R-Studio`.

Comment: @BenBolker, sometimes you are in the middle of some work and you don't want to restart `R-Studio`. So, is there a way (a function or something) to load this package successfully without having to restart `R-Studio`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** you probably need to restart R (*not necessarily* restarting RStudio; you can use `Session > Restart R`, which will restart your R session within RStudio).

`?detach` has a fairly involved description of what *doesn't* happen when you detach packages, and advises you to restart R if you need a clean environment. This is unfortunate, but it's the way it is.

> If a package has a namespace, detaching it does not by default
> unload the namespace (and may not even with ‘unload = TRUE’), and
> detaching will not in general unload any dynamically loaded
> compiled code (DLLs); see ‘getLoadedDLLs’ and
> ‘library.dynam.unload’.  Further, registered S3 methods from the
> namespace will not be removed, and because S3 methods are not
> tagged to their source on registration, it is in general not
> possible to safely un-register the methods associated with a given
> package. If you use ‘library’ on a package whose namespace is
> loaded, it attaches the exports of the already loaded namespace.
> So detaching and re-attaching a package may not refresh some or
> all components of the package, and is inadvisable. The most
> reliable way to completely detach a package is to restart R.

On a slightly broader note, if you have a clean workflow you generally *should* be able to start a new R session and get back to where you were without too much hassle:

- if you some of your code takes a long time to re-run, you should probably be using `targets` or `make` (not an R package!) or some other workflow tool to avoid re-running upstream steps
- if you can't rely on re-running your code to get you back to where you were, your workflow is inherently fragile/dangerous ...

[This](https://rstats.wtf/save-source.html) provides some useful advice on managing workflows in R.